# How to get data from sqlite after sorting?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I need your help once more.
I want to get the top 3 values from my sqlite database and store them in QStrings or int's.
My database has 1 table, and that table has 3 collumns (name, wins, losses).
I want to do something like:

```
QString name1;
QSqlQuery qrry;
qrry.exec("SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY wins DESC WHERE rowid=1");

if (qrry.isActive())
{
    while(qrry.next())
    {
        name1=qrry.value(0).toString();
    }
}
```

If I remove `ORDER BY wins DESC`, I get the first name from db. But I want to sort it first and `ORDER BY` is not looking like the right way to do this.
Can you please help me?

Comment: Why is order by not the right way to do this? I use it all the time in my Qt  applications.

Comment: Why do you put a `WHERE` clause in your statement ?

Comment: I suppose you should use `LIMIT 3` clause, not `WHERE rowid=1`

Comment: Agreed `order by`  does not make sense with the `WHERE rowid=1` part.

Comment: @hank, how can I read the names stored in database in different QStrings if I use LIMIT? Like.. "name1=1st name in db", "name2=2nd name", "name3=3rd name".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @hank said, your query should be:

```
qrry.exec("SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY wins DESC LIMIT 3");
```

`LIMIT` clause allows you to only get a limited number of results in your resultset.  In this case, you will only get the `name` value of the 3 maximum values of `wins` column.

The `WHERE` clause you wrote had no reason to be there.

---

**EDIT:**

> how can I read the names like this: "name1=first name in db", "name2=2nd name", "name3=3rd name" using LIMIT ?

If you want to get the 3 names in 3 different variables, you could write something like this:

```
QString name1, name2, name3;

if (qrry.isActive())
{
    int i = 0;
    while(qrry.next())
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0:
                name1 = qrry.value(0).toString();
                break;
            case 1:
                name2 = qrry.value(0).toString();
                break;
            case 2:
                name3 = qrry.value(0).toString();
                break;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

It is one way to do it but you could also put the names in an array or a vector. In your case, it doesn't really matter because you only want the 3 first names but if you wanted to keep more than 10 or 50 names, it would be easier to deal with arrays or vectors.

`LIMIT 3` clause ensures that you will have maximum 3 results in your resultset and that you will only loop 3 times in your `while(qrry.next())` loop.

Comment: Ok, I got this, but how can I read the names like this: "name1=first name in db", "name2=2nd name", "name3=3rd name" using LIMIT ?

Comment: @Alex using the loop you wrote in your question

Comment: @Alex I just edited my answer with one way to do it. I didn't test it but it should do what you want.